# Single embedded Ignite node always performs recovery on startup and it takes too long

Tags: ignite

I am evaluating Ignite in a proof-of-concept application that loads a reasonable amount of data into a single embedded node with persistence enabled. The on-disk storage is about 20 GB and I have allocated 8 GB of RAM (out of 16 available) to in-memory cache.

After loading this initial data into the database, I find that startups take way too long to be practical, especially for a development cycle. The total startup time is about 12 minutes. Looking at the log, there are two steps that account for most of the time:

```
i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager : Binary recovery performed in 127946 ms.
i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager : Logical recovery performed in 571725 ms.
```

I'm aware that when I press "stop" in the debugger, it terminates the process and Ignite won't have a chance to clean up properly. However, before this run, I let Ignite run all night so that it would be allowed to perform all intended checkpointing etc. It seems no matter what I do the startup time remains high.

Questions:

- Is this expected / normal behavior?
- If so, how can I achieve an acceptable code/build/run cycle? I think a startup of more than five seconds would hamper our developers.
- Also, if this is normal, what are strategies for reducing the startup time in a production environment? This test has me worried that restarts will take too long. I think anything more than five minutes would sit badly with our IT ops people and customers.
- If it's not normal, what am I doing wrong?

The full log file is too large for Stack Overflow but available on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Ue74y3W1).

Comment: Do you really have to retain the whole database contents between runs in development?

Comment: @alamar yes we do.

Comment: Is there any difference in start-up time if you put stored data on RAM drive?

Comment: I don't have enough RAM to make a 20 GB RAM drive, sorry. But it seems fairly obvious to me that it would start faster since, I assume, the bottleneck is I/O. I can see in the task manager that the process reads about 12 GB of data during startup.

Comment: I think you should only use Ignite's persistence if you have plenty of resources, such as RAM and I/O. It is not really optimized for resource-constrained scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only use Ignite's persistence if you have plenty of resources, such as RAM and I/O. It is not really optimized for resource-constrained scenarios.

Maybe you can have a cluster on server(s) and only connect clients for development? This way you can restart it once a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t sound normal. If Ignite is stopped abruptly then it will take some time to replay write-ahead-logs to bring the persistence files to a consistent state. However, 12 minutes sound suspicious, especially, if Ignite was stopped normally with a method like Ignite.stop.

You are right that the startup time shouldn’t be affected only because you cannot cache all the data set in RAM. It will impact performance of operations but not of the bootstrap procedures.

Try to run your app on a different machine or environment. Something might be wrong with your laptop or its disks. Try to check smaller data size or stop Ignite gently with Ignite.stop to ensure there is no write-ahead-logs or recovery activities reported in the logs.

Comment: I tried starting it up and then stopping it gracefully but it didn't seem to help. Suppose I could try starting fresh with a new database and just loading all the data up again.

Comment: Yes, it is the preferred approach when testing. I also remember some of tickets where Ignite did some extra work on persistent startup. So it may improve in coming versions.